# Automatic Reload of Java Trust Store without needing Restart of Web Server process

Tags: refresh, reload, x509, truststore

I have a web app whose rest endpoints I have secured using X.509 Public Key Authentication mechanism. To explain it in bit detail, I had to add my sample clients' public certificates into my server web apps' java trust store. Off course my server also have one java key store containing a server key pair. So all good here and any server calls which pass valid client certificates get authenticated seamlessly. no issues.

In future, I will need to add new client certificates into same server trust store as per need. Addition of new client certificates into server trust store is an offline process and would be taken care through some tool like java keytool.

But I don't want to restart my server process in order to refresh with the additional client certificates in the trust store. I want my server process to automatically reload its trust store whenever any new client certificate gets added to the trust store.

I am even open to sending a trigger event through some http hook to my server process for initiating the trust store reload. But nothing like automatic reload. Any pointers ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reloading a java.net.http.HttpClient's SSLContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69506869/reloading-a-java-net-http-httpclients-sslcontext)